# Accessing the UserInfo Endpoint in IdentityServer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, identityserver4

I have an app that, despite implementing `IProfileService` and adding the claims to the context.IssuedClaims collection, they still aren't accessible in my client app.
So I figured (from reading other threads on this topic on here) that I need to call the `UserInfo` endpoint to get this data?

The thing is, I'm not sure what value to put in the `UserInfoRequest` object for the token value that is passed to `GetUserInfoAsync`.

I have the following to be invoked from the index action of the controller of my MVC client:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
            var discovery = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(Common.Constants.GlobalConfig.IDENTITY_SERVER_ENDPOINT);
            if (discovery.IsError) throw new Exception(discovery.Error);
            var tokenClient = new TokenClient(discovery.TokenEndpoint, Constants.ClientList.VIEW_MY_BILLS, "secret");
            var tokenResponse = tokenClient.???

            var response = client.GetUserInfoAsync(new UserInfoRequest
            {
                Address = discovery.UserInfoEndpoint,
                Token = User.???
            }
```

Am I on the right track here to get additional data about the user (as claims) and if so, what do I do in the example above to complete the call to the UserInfo endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You call it using the access_token you receive during the sign in process. That token will have the correct user claims and scope to be able to call it.